Why have I got a question ban?
I'm asking questions on this site and I haven't got any admonishments or warnings up to now. All of a sudden I have got this question ban. I would like to know the reasons of this procedure.

All algorithmically imposed question bans have the same cause and the same cure, as detailed in this FAQ.
Please read through that question and its answer very carefully, for within them is contained all you need to know about this.
